# What is the degree of a leaf node?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm

I have a confusion. I have read that no. of children a node can have in a tree is called its degree. So, a binary tree is of degree two as max. no. of children a node in binary tree is 2. **Hence, leaf node is of degree 0.**

However, according to graph theory, a leaf node (vertex) has degree 1. In, terms of graphs, I can understand that a leaf vertex has degree 1 as only one edge incidents on it. But how is it true in case of trees?

So, firstly I want to know is that, is there any concept of leaf vertex in case of graphs? (graphs, not trees)

Secondly, why there's written that A leaf is a vertex of degree 1 in the following link of tree-
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)

I am talking everything in perspective of Data Structures.

Answer (score 4):

In graph theory (part of mathematics), the degree of a vertex is the total number of edges connecting to it.

In *computer science*, the degree of a vertex in a tree is the total number of *children* it has - which is the number of edges minus one (except for the root node).

Comment: And this difference arises in part because a graph theoretic tree is an *undirected* graph, so you cannot distinguish any one node as the parent of another, and also because in graph theory, "degree" is defined for vertices in any graph, not just trees.

Comment: I read the degree of a leaf vertex in a graph is 1. (in data structure). What about that?

Comment: @programmer_ They're using the graph theory definition of "degree".

Comment: @programmer_, the answer already explains that the the term is defined differently in different fields.  The graph theoretic term "leaf *vertex*" does not go with the computer science term "data structure".  The term "node" is usually preferred in the context of the "tree" data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Degree of leaf node in tree is always Zero(0)....

Because Number of sub-trees of particular node is the degree of that node in tree.
And Leaf Node has no any sub trees.so Degree of Leaf Node is Zero(0).
..
Thank You

Comment: Do you mean indegree is 1, outdegree is 0?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences: "the degree of a leaf is 0" and "the degree of a leaf is 1" are correct. The issue here is that they are referred to two different math objects.

A tree is a undirected graph, thus a leaf must have degree 1 as it is connected only to its parent (degree = number of incident edges).

However a Tree is also the name of a data structure that simulates a hierarchical tree structure: this is a rooted tree, a directed graph whose underlying undirected graph is a tree ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))). For such object the degree is defined as the "Number of sub trees of a node" thus the degree of a leaf is zero.

Comment: Here too, do you mean indegree is 1, outdegree is 0?

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy In the first case no, a Tree is an undirected graph thus there is no in/out degree, just degree. In the second case yes because a rooted tree is a directed graph.

Answer (score 1):

In data structure the tree is treated as a directed graph. So ot will hold all the theorems of directed graph. But in mathematics graph theory tree is a non directed graph. So the property like total degree = 2* no of edges in maths will be total degree = no. Of edges in Data structure